# Type errors on auth wrapper for getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I created an an auth wrapper for `getServerSideProps` in Next.js. I'm having some type errors though in the hook, and on the pages that require it. Here is the wrapper code followed by the TypeScript errors. Please note this is a pretty strict implementation of TypeScript.

```js
import { deleteCookie, hasCookie } from 'cookies-next'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export function withAuth(gssp: GetServerSideProps) {
  return async ctx => { // error 1
    const { req, res } = ctx
    const hasToken = hasCookie('token', { req, res })

    if (!hasToken) {
      deleteCookie('token', { req, res })
      deleteCookie('user', { req, res })
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/login',
          permanent: false,
        },
        props: {},
      }
    }
    const gsspData = await gssp(ctx)

    return {
      props: {
        ...gsspData?.props, // error 2
        hasToken,
      },
    }
  }
}
```

```
// error-1:
Parameter 'ctx' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)

// error-2:
Property 'props' does not exist on type 'GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any; }>'.
  Property 'props' does not exist on type '{ redirect: Redirect; }'.ts(2339)
```

and here is the implementation with error as well:

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = withAuth(ctx => { // error at CTX
  return { props: {} }
})
```

```
// error-3 
Argument of type '(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext<ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>) => { props: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetServerSideProps<{ [key: string]: any; }, ParsedUrlQuery, PreviewData>'.
  Type '{ props: {}; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<{ [key: string]: any; }>>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2345)
```

Any illumination on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a missing explicit type, and some type narrowing that needs to happen to make TypeScript happy.

For the first error, because you're using strict typing, TypeScript complains because `ctx` as implicit type of `any`. You can use the `GetServerSidePropsContext` to properly type `ctx`.

For the second error, TypeScript is not able to determine the right type for `gsspData` by itself (out of the possible types it can have), so we can help with that by narrowing it down with `'props' in gsspData ? gsspData.props : {}`. This narrowing ensure `props` exists in `gsspData` so we can safely call `gsspData.props`.

```js
import { deleteCookie, hasCookie } from 'cookies-next'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export function withAuth(gssp: GetServerSideProps) {
    // Explicitly type `ctx` as `GetServerSidePropsContext`
    return async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
        const { req, res } = ctx
        const hasToken = hasCookie('token', { req, res })

        if (!hasToken) {
            deleteCookie('token', { req, res })
            deleteCookie('user', { req, res })

            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/login',
                    permanent: false
                }
                // No need to return `props` when redirecting
            }
        }

        const gsspData = await gssp(ctx)

        return {
            props: {
                // Narrow down `gsspData` type
                ...('props' in gsspData ? gsspData.props : {}),
                hasToken
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the function passed to `withAuth` needs to return a promise (because it's typed as `gssp: GetServerSideProps`). We can simply fix the error by making the function `async`.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = withAuth(async (ctx) => {
    // Your logic here
    return { props: {} }
})
```